# Any way to use a dynamic value in Wait Condition?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have several workflows where the users want to set the number of days before a date defined in an entity (e.g. contract end date) to receive a notice. Within a Wait Condition, is there a way to set the number of days before to an int attribute in the entity, rather than hard code it?  Any workarounds if that is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to do this out of th ebox.  The best way for you to do this, assuming you're using a dropdown for the day values, would be to code each branch of wait logic for each selected value in the dropdown.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a drop down, as basically any date if valid, for many years ahead the current date.  I ended up having two fields, one a days field and one the actual date field used by the workflow. I then calculate the date for the work flow using the onchange event.  Lot of work for something that should be easier. Thanks!